# Error when trying to install .sh file for USB wifi driver

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, adapter

I have been trying to install the driver for a USB Wifi Adapter 802 .11ac (Realtex I think).

This has been a difficult process.  The device came with a CD Rom.  What I have done is:

1. Open the folder LINUX/8811AUlinux (there is another folder called RTL81888192EUS_linux_v4.3.0.4_11485.20140519... which has similar looking files including an install.sh file which I tried installing to no avail)
2. Extract the files in "RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407.zip" to a new folder Documents/USB Wifi
3. Open the folder location in terminal by right-clicking the folder and choosing "open in terminal" (glad I finally figured out that shortcut)
4. Run the command "sudo bash install.sh" - i had tried without sudo privilege and ran into an authentication error.
5. I get a long string of text and then this at the end:

Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.8.0-38-generic/build M=/home/n/Documents/USB Wifi/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-38-generic'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'Wifi/RTL8821AU_Linux_v5.2.6_21981_COEX20170206-6760.20170407/driver/rtl8821AU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.6_21981.20170407_COEX20170206-6760'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-38-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:1877: modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################

This is what the adapter seems to show up like when I type "lsusb" in terminal:
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.  I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on a Thinkpad T530.  Thank you.

Comment: This driver won't install on Ubuntu 20.04. You need to know what is the wireless chip and find an answer with a manual.

Comment: Please post results from terminal for `lsusb` with the usb wifi plugged in

Comment: Thank you!  I think most likely I will take the advice to find another usb driver since it sounds unlikely that I can get it to work, and honestly it's a relief to know there may be adapters out there that just work!  However I'll post the lsusb results above and will be open to exploring that slightly further if there's much possibility there for a solution.

Comment: @user535733  Best driver installer advice on the web...the way to a better user experience is to follow these instructions to the letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `mokutil --sb-state` as Secure Boot needs to be disabled, then in terminal do

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8821cu.git
cd 8821cu
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

Reboot

Comment: Thank you for your help!  When I enter mokutil --sb-state I get "Command 'mokutil' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install mokutil:"  Should I install it?  Also is there something I need to do additionally do disable Secure Boot, and is that permanent or temporary?  Lastly do those other steps get entered all at once in terminal or one at a time?

Comment: If mokutil isn't installed, just run the other commands

Comment: Thank you.  The first two seem successful and then when I try cd rtl8821cu I get "bash: cd: rtl8821cu: No such file or directory"

Comment: I just fixed that, should be `cd 8821`

Comment: Hmm... "bash: cd: 8821: No such file or directory"...

Comment: Tried cd 8821cu again and it worked!  Thank you very much!

Comment: Solution working fine with Techkey Wi-Fi 11ac USB Adapter on freshly updated Linux Mint 20.1 ulyssa 1st June 2021